# Filling in missing rows omitted in the result of a 'select' statement

Tags: sql, select, impala

Is there a way to fill in rows omitted in the result of a `select` statement?

I have data like this:

```
person,day
1,20
1,24
```

...that is returned by a simple query like this:

```sql
select *
from example_table
where day>=20
```

Want I want is to add rows for the missing days so the result looks like this:

```
person,day
1,20
1,21
1,22
1,23
1,24
```

Is there a way to do this via SQL?

Comment: `SELECT person,day FROM table 
UNION
SELECT '1','12' FROM table`. Like this ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using impala. so, please without window functions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a help table with one integer column with values from 1 to max value (31?).

```
select person, day
from yourtable
UNION ALL
select intcol, 
from helptable h
where not exists (select day from yourtable y where y.day = h.helptable);
```

Comment: Yes, that could be solution, but user table is huge, dates table is also huge and doing cross join to make help table...It's not gonna work :(

Comment: You can't avoid using help table in this problem. But help table can be generated dynamically and not stored permanently.